# string formatting a sql query in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been playing around with sqlite3, and I get an **sqlite3.OperationalError: near "sweet": syntax error** for this line of my code `query_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(%d, %s, %f, %s, %d)" % (ids[num],names[num], price[num], descriptions[num], calories[num]))` When I put in the values in 3 separate queries the code seems to work, but I'm trying to keep my code more DRY by using a for loop. The code so far:

```
import sqlite3

filename = sqlite3.connect("McDonalds_Menu.db")
query_cursor = filename.cursor()

def create_table():
    query_cursor.execute( "CREATE TABLE mcdonalds_menu (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(20), price DECIMAL(3, 2), description TEXT, calories INTEGER)")

ids = range(1,4)
names = ["McFlurry", "Fillet-o-Fish", "McCafe"]
price = 1.50, 2.25, 0.99
descriptions = ["Delicious sweet icecream", "Best fish in the sea", "Freshly brewed Colombian coffee"]
calories = 220, 450, 75

def data_entry():
    for num in xrange(3):
        query_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(%d, %s, %f, %s, %d)" % (ids[num], names[num], price[num], descriptions[num], calories[num]))    
    filename.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
    data_entry()
```

Is it possible to string format a sql query using a loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL needs strings in `VALUES` to be quoted. Integers and floats do not need to be quoted.

In the commented output below, notice that the SQL `VALUES` contains unquoted strings for "Fillet-o-Fish" and "Best fish in the sea":

```
sql = "INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(%d, %s, %f, %s, %d)".format(ids[num], names[num], price[num], descriptions[num], calories[num])
# INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(2, Fillet-o-Fish, 2.250000, Best fish in the sea, 450)
```

Adding some escaped quotes around your string values produces valid SQL:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(%d, \"%s\", %f, \"%s\", %d)" % (ids[num],names[num], price[num], descriptions[num], calories[num])
# INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES(2, "Fillet-o-Fish", 2.250000, "Best fish in the sea", 450)
```

Comment: Please be aware that you're allowing SQL injection with this technique.

Answer (score 10):

All the other answers relying on python's string manipulation are insecure and might not correctly escape quotes in your strings.

The best way to do it, as suggested in `sqlite3` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=parameter%20substitution), is to use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. In your example, it would look like this:

```py
menu_items = [(1, 'McFlurry', 1.5, 'Delicious sweet icecream', 220),
              (2, 'Fillet-o-Fish', 2.25, 'Best fish in the sea', 450),
              (3, 'McCafe', 0.99, 'Freshly brewed Colombian coffee', 75)
              ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO mcdonalds_menu VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', menu_items)
```

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.6+ you can simplify this quoting mess with f strings. For example:

```
c.execute(f"select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='{table_name}';")
for r in c.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

In this snippet, the important thing to note is `f` preceding the sql string. This allows one to pass in variables surrounded by curly braces, in my example: '{table_name}'